# Azure deployment update - Mismatch between the certificates of the running service and the certificates in the uploaded sdk package

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to change the remote desktop certificate of an older application running in Azure.

I created the new certificate, exported it and succesfully uploaded it to the cloud service certificates (in Azure portal)

So far so good but when I try to update the cloud service by uploading a new package with the new certificate then I get this error:

```
Mismatch between the certificates of the running service and the certificates in the uploaded sdk package
```

How can I overcome this? The cloud service builds and works fine if I keep the old certificate thumbprint.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the thumbprints of the certificate uploaded to the portal is the same with what you provided in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg.

Comment: I checked. It is. When I select the new certificate in the package dialog all the cscfg files are updated with the new thumbprint

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are doing things right for RDP cert. I have a pair of pfx made from [makecert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.100).aspx) and upload them to cloud service, and can switch thumbprints around in CSCFG file without any deployment problem.

My assumption is, you have used this cert else where in your service resulted the error.

Referring to [step 2 in this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal/), is it possible you are using cert but missing something in the service definition(CSDEF)? Such as CA certificate reference or intermediate certificate block.